# Java regular expression to match the pattern for equals sign between two or more words that has an exclamatory as a delimeter between the ranges

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that matches all the following given pattern examples -

```
1) Name=John!Age=25!Gender=M
2) Name=John!Name2=Sam!Name3=Josh
3) Name=John!Name2=Sam!Name3=Josh!
```

Basically there has to be an equals to sign between two words or numbers followed by an exclamatory and then the pattern repeats. the pattern can only end with an exclamatory or any alphabets or numbers or spaces but not the 'equals' sign or any other special characters

So these examples should not be matched -

```
1) Name!John=Name2+Sam=
2) Name=John=
3) Name=John!!
4) Name=John-
```

I'm very new to regular expressions and I just learnt a few basic things and I have this following regular expression written so far which doesn't fully satisfy my requirement `((?:\w+|=)*)!`

I'm still trying to modify my regular expression to match my requirement, any help/guidance will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:\w+=\w+!)*\w+=\w+!?$
```

In Java

```
String regex = "^(?:\\w+=\\w+!)*\\w+=\\w+!?$";
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\w+=\w+!)*` Optionally repeat 1+ word chars `=` 1+ word chars and `!`
- `\w+=\w+!?` Match 1+ word chars `=` 1+ word chars and optional `!`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/68NMZx/1)

```
String[] strings = {
    "Name=John!Age=25!Gender=M",
    "Name=John!Name2=Sam!Name3=Josh",
    "Name=John!Name2=Sam!Name3=Josh!",
    "N=J!A=25!",
    "a=ba=b",
    "Name!John=Name2+Sam=",
    "Name=John=",
    "Name=John!!",
    "Name=John-"
};

for (String s : strings) {
    if (s.matches("(?:\\w+=\\w+!)*\\w+=\\w+!?")) {
        System.out.println("Match: " + s);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No match: " + s);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Match: Name=John!Age=25!Gender=M
Match: Name=John!Name2=Sam!Name3=Josh
Match: Name=John!Name2=Sam!Name3=Josh!
Match: N=J!A=25!
No match: a=ba=b
No match: Name!John=Name2+Sam=
No match: Name=John=
No match: Name=John!!
No match: Name=John-
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation and I apologize for not being more specific, the following pattern should also match N=J!A=25! so basically it should also match 1+ word chars and also a single char.

Comment: @Sangli This string `N=J!A=25!` also matches. See https://regex101.com/r/EirmFa/1

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation, this worked